# How to get my cox.zph(cpfit.sd) output as a csv file instead of just in the console

Tags: r, survival-analysis

Here is the script for my cox model:

```
# Fit a Cox model (Use data=int.data if you want to include the intensities from a measurement channel in the cox model)
cpfit.sd <- coxph(Surv(Time,Event)~Sci_SampleID,data=prim.data)
cph.pval <- summary(cpfit.sd)$coef
cph.hr <- summary(cpfit.sd)$coefficients
summary(cpfit.sd)
cox.zph(cpfit.sd)
```

lrtest <- survdiff(Surv(Time, as.logical(Event)) ~ Sci_SampleID,data=prim.data,rho=0)
lrtest

I would like to get my output data from the above exported as a csv file.

I was able to do the following:
write.csv(cph.hr,paste(root.dir,output.file,sep=""))

however this does not give me the full data set, and it won't allow me to do a similar function for the cox.zph file. I always receive this error:

Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) :
cannot coerce class ‘"cox.zph"’ to a data.frame

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I feel `broom::tidy` could be easier than `summary`.

```
cph.hr <- broom::tidy(fit, conf.int = TRUE, exponetiante = TRUE)
write.csv(cph.hr, "cph_hr.csv")
```

For a cox.zph object, you could try:

```
zph<- cox.zph(cpfit.sd)$table
write.csv(zph, "zph.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately this did not work:

Comment: > zph<- cox.zph(cpfit.sd)$table
Error in solve.default(imat, u) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[3,3] = 0
> cph.hr <- broom::tidy(fit, conf.int = TRUE, exponetiante = TRUE)
Error in broom::tidy(fit, conf.int = TRUE, exponetiante = TRUE) : 
  object 'fit' not found
> write.csv(cph.hr, "cph_hr.csv")
> zph<- cox.zph(cpfit.sd)$table
Error in solve.default(imat, u) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[3,3] = 0
> write.csv(zph, "zph.csv")
Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'zph' not found

Comment: `fit` should the model `cpfit.sd` you previously fitted using `coxph`.